# FILE in C and different output

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("loop.txt" , "r");
    printf("%p\n",fp);
}
```

output :

```
     Run 1 : 0x101d010
     Run 2 : 0x13f9010
     Run 3 : 0xeaf010
```

**Why is the output different every time ?**

Comment: Why do you think it should be always the same value?

Comment: The answer is probably [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).

Comment: @Damien sorry ,I do not have the answer

Comment: user14528249 Why is the pointer value of interest?  Why do your care if it is the same or different between runs?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Let's consider it out of curiosity, Why is the output different every time ?

Comment: 3 pointers are of the binary form "0000,000x,xxxx,xxxx,xxx1,0000,0001,0000".  With more samples, a strong pattern may emerge hinting at the underlying process.  In particular, about how many before a repeat occurs?  3 is a small sample to support "different every time".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fopen()` function call returns a pointer to a `FILE` structure that 'describes' the file, in terms of what the operating system needs in order to access that file on disk. That `FILE` structure will be located somewhere in memory (allocated at run-time); the *actual location* (address) of that memory block will vary between different runs of the program - which is exactly *why* you need to keep track of it in your `fp` (pointer) variable.

All other calls to library functions (such as `fwrite()`, `fread()` and `fclose()`), which access that file, will need that `fp` variable as a parameter; this indicates to the functions (and to the system) which file object you are working with.

To give an *authoritative and detailed* explanation about ***why*** your program receives a different address in the file pointer, each time you run it, would require equally detailed and authoritative knowledge of your system's implementation of the `fopen()` call (and related I/O support code) – and that is knowledge that I don't have.

However, here are two *possible* explanations:

1. Each time you call `fopen()`, the system allocates space for the required `FILE` structure by calling `malloc(sizeof(FILE))`; this will return the address of the first available chunk of system memory of sufficient size, which will clearly vary between runs, depending on what other programs and/or services are using the system's memory pool.
2. The I/O subsystem has a *fixed*, internal table of `FILE` structures, each with its (fixed) starting address; when you call `fopen()`, the system assigns the first available table entry to your opened file and the function returns the address of that. But this can also vary between runs, depending on what other programs/services are using entries in that table.

If I had to make a guess (and that's *all* it would be), the large differences between the addresses you show in your example would tend to make me favour the first possibility. But there are numerous other ways your system could handle the task.

Comment: ASLR! This used to be not true and debug paths used to reliably corrupt the heap the exact same way every time.

Comment: Is the location saved in Virtual memory ?

Comment: I am new to computer architecture, and I have been asked this question  " Why is the output different every time " So I try to arrive at a clearer and more comprehensive answer
Thank you for the clear answers, but if there are more details, I hope you will write it

Comment: You gave me a very good idea and I can answer based on this explanation. Thank you for the answer